# Trigger Ready Flow /Process Builder to open record in edit mode (URL/e)

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, urlhacking, url, automation

I would like to use an auto-flow (ie. not use a button, but use trigger ready flow /process builder to auto-launch a flow) to open up a current record in Edit mode. Ie. Hack the URL so that the URL ends with '/e'.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I could go about this?

Comment: Why? What is your business case?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to have a pop-up that comes up when certain conditions occur in Salesforce. Unfortunately, Flow cannot do either of these items. Trigger-ready flow cannot present any kind of screens at all; it is an inherent restriction of the system for which there is no workaround. It also cannot "open records" in edit mode or otherwise; the closest you could get is presenting a link for a user to click, but that would require the user to click a button or link first.

Alternatively, you could do this with some complex Visualforce and Javascript work. I'm not a developer, but theoretically, this could be done, though it would take a significant amount of code.